# laravel disable query logging

Tags: php, laravel

I can only assume this is the reason as there are a lot of DB queries happening on my site and I am not familiar with Laravel
My server memory is increasing constantly to the point of the server dying so is there a way to disable the query logging completely without editing every page that is doing DB queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search the project for: `enableQueryLog` then  remove it. https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/database#query-logging

You might also want to visit storage/logs and clear those out.

Comment: sorry should have said, this is v4.0

Comment: 4.2 has `DB::connection()->disableQueryLog();` 4.0 though, not 100% sure. Have you tried searching the project for `Log::`?

Comment: Actually 4.1. Added DB::disableQueryLog();
DB::connection()->disableQueryLog(); to artisan.php - made no difference. dunno how you add code here

Comment: Every new page that is visited I see the server buff/cache memory go up and up and up.

Comment: Might not be artisan.php - what about adding it to your controller(s)?

Comment: I wouldn't even know where to look for that, this is a theme design using Laravel and prior 7 days ago I had never used this framework

Comment: app/Http/Controllers

Comment: What are you using to edit this project? Do you have the whole thing open? try cmd+shift+f to search the entire directory you have open. If you don't have anything open, try downloading notepad++, atom, or sublime

Comment: + if you hover over my comments, there's a little triangle to the left - you can click that to give me points for answering questions and such.

Answer (score 7):

You can disable query logs like this:

For single connection:

```
DB::connection('CONNECTION_NAME')->disableQueryLog();
```

For whole DB:

```
DB::disableQueryLog();
```

Documentation:

https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Connection.html#method_disableQueryLog

Answer (score 0):

If you want to also clear the query log, use `DB::flushQueryLog()`.